# Can't bind to 'groupDisplayType' since it isn't a known property of 'ag-grid-angular'

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to bind groupDisplayType property but it looks like the property has been dropped in the recent version of Ag-Grid. I am using 25.1.0.

```
<ag-grid-angular
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [groupDisplayType]="groupDisplayType"
    /* other grid options ... */>
</ag-grid-angular>
```

Error:

```
NG8002: Can't bind to 'groupDisplayType' since it isn't a known property of 'ag-grid-angular'.
1. If 'ag-grid-angular' is an Angular component and it has 'groupDisplayType' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ag-grid-angular' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

6     [groupDisplayType]="groupDisplayType"
```

There are some online examples available on Ag-grid website but they seem to be using older version of ag-grid.

Is there any alternate method available to bind `groupDisplayType`?

Comment: The docs still say it's a valid property of the grid. Does your module import AgGridModule properly?

Comment: yes, I have verified once again. It has been implemented as per https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/getting-started/. I am able to use all other ag-grid enterprise edition properties too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of `groupDisplayType` was only introduced to Ag Grid on version `26.0.0`.

You will need to upgrade to 26+ to be able to use it. When working with older versions of Ag Grid always use the documentation relevant to your version, in this case: https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/25.1.0/angular-grid/